# unable to delete the directory while executing a batch via cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm having trouble deleting the sub-directory, while I'm executing the following batch via cmd. The mentioned dir is getting deleted, and I'm getting the relevant log file of the deleted files, but the sub-dir isn't getting deleted. Since it ain't getting deleted, I don't have a proper log file.

Here is the code that I'm executing,

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

:: set folder path 
set dump_path=%1

:: set min age of files and folders to delete 
set max_days=%2

shift
shift

:: remove files from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>logfile.log"

:: remove subdirectories from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path && echo @path>>logfile.log"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the pic, in that further, I added a folder with some contents to check, but it ain't working.

[image]

More info, as it still ain't working, any way to change it into a PowerShell execution?

Below pic, before executing the cmd,

[image]

Post execution of the cmd,

[image]

Still, I'm unable to understand why it isn't removing the sub-dir files...This time, I removed the sub-dir cmd from my batch and added a '/S' to my first cmd.

Comment: All I get is the following error every time I execute the batch with the sub-dir cmd, "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."

Comment: You are looking for a directory, called "*.*", are you sure you have dots in the name of your directory?

Comment: @Dominique that "." is for the file extension

Comment: Yes, but you use that for both file search and directory search. I believe that's a mistake.

Comment: @Dominique if I remove those '.' then I get "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." @_@

Comment: It most probably means that there are no directories to delete.

Comment: @Dominique If you see the image I added, there I added one folder with some contents to check the batch...but the contents inside the folder aren't getting deleted, whereas if I give a direct command of 'del' that's working and removing everything in the image path including the sub-dir

Comment: When you launch your script, you give two parameters: first is the directory, second the maximum age of your file. The file you want to delete is two days old. If you give 1 or 0 as a value, it won't work. Besides, can you alter your Windows explorer, showing extensions? It looks like your file doesn't have an extension.

Comment: @Dominique the files I'm deleting are min 15+ days old, so the cmd I'm giving is `15>nul` as the second argument.

Comment: When you use `forfiles.exe`, it performs a separate `cmd.exe` process, for each matching item. What is less well known, is that in doing so, each command is run with the directory path of that item as the current working directory. A problem you will therefore encounter is you cannot remove a directory if it is the current working directory. You will need to therefore explicitly change directory, or echo all of your matches to a holding file, remove everything read from that file, then append its contents to the intended log, before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your batchfile:

- You mention you want to remove the files with are older than 15 days, but in your batchfile you remove the files which are more recent than 15 days (there's a minus in front of the `%max_days%`, not a plus, you need to change that).
- You mention launching the batchfile, using `15>nul` as a second parameter, which is wrong. It should simply be `15`.

Comment: If I don't give that '-' sign, then it ain't working, and I tried giving `15>nul` as I wanted to avoid the failure of the batch, which happens many times, as I'm not checking the values in my batch whether they are null or not. @dominique